# what is difference between posedge, negedge and event clk?

Tags: verilog, fpga, verification, system-verilog

Why we are using `posedge clk` in the designs we are using. Mostly `negedge clk` used for Flipflops. And, `negedge clk` will give Low Power.

Clarify me one thing that what is difference between posedge, negedge and event clk triggering and internal mechanism behind it. Give me some applications where we actually use which type of triggering mechanism.

Let us take below examples

1. ```
   initial clk=0;
   always
     #5 clk=~clk; //Clock starting from 0
   ```
2. ```
   initial clk=1;
   always
     #5 clk=~clk;// Clock starting from 1
   ```

What is different between these two programs? Is there any change will occur in triggering clk to circuit?

Comment: Perhaps this would be better asked on EE StackExchange?  This isn't a programming question and is likely to solicit opinion.

Comment: The first paragraph does not make sense to me. The examples you give are not synthesisable so they represent no circuit. The examples do not illustrate anything to do with the posedge and negedge at the start of the question.

Comment: I saw Phillipe dunned you on EE StackExchange for a duplicate question here. The idea would have been to withdraw the question here before someone provided an answer not useful to you preventing the question from being withdrawn.  Morgan appears to make a valid point, that your question doesn't appear to be connected to your examples, nor would it be obvious to the casual reader that your premise that a "`negedge clk` will give Low Power".  There is no evidence of this in FPGA architectures commonly used (and you tag your question with the FPGA tag).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, designs work with rising edges (posedge). Falling edges (negedge) are needed for:

- multi cycle paths
- a generic DDR description
- other special I/O protocols

**I think this is a stereotype:**
In Europe, a clock starts with a high period followed by low, whereas in America the clock starts with low followed by a high period.

=> It's a question of defining the clock.

<strike>I'm not aware of any power savings from using negedge.</strike>

Comment: See [Clock Gating and Negative Edge Triggering for Energy Recovery Clock](http://online.sfsu.edu/mahmoodi/papers/paper_C44.pdf). You won't find such techniques widely used, certainly no in [Low Power FPGAs](http://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_download/129917-ac323-dynamic-power-reduction-in-flash-fpgas-app-note).

Comment: @DavidKoontz Thanks for these papers. You linked a Microsemi document, do have experiences with Microsemi FPGAs? If so, I would like to ask some questions about these FPGAs and tools :) (And how do I contact you in private or by PM ...?)

Comment: Nothing recent, back in the days they were Actel. It was primarily a search for low power FPGAs.